# Convert a string to value of control

Tags: asp.net

I have a string **str** = "txtName.Text" (txtName is name of textbox control)

How to display **value of textbox** without is value of string **str** (use C#)

Let me a solution.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: "How to display value of textbox without is value of string str"? What?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding this. Do you want to look up the value of a control by using the string "txtName.Text"? If so, on the client or server? Also, could you give some more detail of the problem.

Comment: I must say I am confused by the question. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Andrew Hare's solution helped me. Sorry because my English is not clear. Thanks about your ideas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to extract the control id like this:

```
String controlId = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('.'));
```

Then use the [`Page.FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx) method to find the control and cast that as an `ITextControl` so that you can get the `Text` property value:

```
ITextControl textControl
    = this.FindControl(controlId) as ITextControl;
if (textControl != null)
{
    // you found a control that has a Text property
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew Hare. This is my problem :) with your help, it's solved.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the question is: *How to get value of textbox control given its ID as a string.*

Use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method.

Example:

```
TextBox myTextBox = FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
if (myTextBox != null)
{
   Response.Write("Value of the text box is: " + myTextBox.Text);
}
else
{
   Response.Write("Control not found");
}
```

Comment: It is better to use `as` for exception-proof casting instead of `is`.  For more info please see my article about this very topic: http://togaroga.com/blog/2009/09/two-casts-are-not-better-than-one/

Answer (score 0):

If by "value" you mean "numeric value", then you can't - text boxes contain strings only. What you can do is get the string like you did, and parse that string into a number.
You can use `int.Parse()` or `double.Parse()` (depending on the type), or `TryParse()` for a safer implementation.